# How to use "head" in ubuntu terminal to see first 10 lines of manual

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I have one questio:

How to use "head" in ubuntu terminal to see first 10 lines of manual E.g. head of grep manual.

I tried somethink like:

```
head man grep
```

Comment: `man grep | head`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
man grep | head
```

The pipe (`|`) is used to redirect output from one command to input for another command. So this command takes the output of `man grep` and provides it as input to `head`.